# Read all mails from inbox

Tags: java, inbox

It reads only new messages from Inbox whereas I want to read all the messages.
How to achieve it?

```
Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY)
Message[] arrayMessages = folderInbox.getMessages();
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the method `Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages(startMessage, endMessage);` instead of `Message[] arrayMessages = folderInbox.getMessages();`

Here the startMessage and endMessage are integer value. A good example taken from here - [enter link description here](http://bharatonjava.wordpress.com/2012/09/15/read-emails-from-inbox/)

```
    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("inbox");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE); // Folder.READ_ONLY
    int messageCount = inbox.getMessageCount();
    System.out.println("Total Messages" + messageCount);
    int startMessage = messageCount - 5;
    int endMessage = messageCount;

    if (messageCount < 5) {
        startMessage = 0;
    }

    Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages(startMessage, endMessage);
```

Comment: I tried the above thing.. but i am still getting the messageCount as 0.

Comment: The messagecount always provide a total number of messages in the inbox. Is your SMTP all set, and retain email after reading. FYI, many SMTP does delete email after delivery from server inbox. One way to check, is to connect to gmail inbox and see how your program behave.

Comment: http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/download-attachments-in-e-mail-messages-using-javamail

Here is the code.... You can also try... Since my messages are not deleted from inbox by SMTP.

Comment: I have achieved it. The file in local folder is getting replaced though everytime i download..

Comment: Great, Please post your answer as well. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.
Changed Server and SSL settings by mail.smtp and overrided Password authentication, connection by IMAP.